# why winston-syslog re-opens connection when .close() is invoked on the logger

Tags: node.js, jestjs, syslog, winston

I have a simple jest test code that creates an instance of a new winston logger using the following transport configuration:

```
it("using TCP protocol", async (done) => {
       const sys: any = new ws.Syslog({
                    host: "localhost",
                    port: 514,
                    protocol: "tcp4",
                    path: "/dev/log",
                    app_name: "ESB",
                    facility: "local5",
                    eol: "\n",
                });
                let syslogger = winston.createLogger({
                    levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
                    transports: [
                      sys
                    ]
                  });

                syslogger.info("test msg");
                syslogger.close();
});
```

The test runs fine and I can see that the messages being received by syslog but the test does not seem to return and hangs after showing the test outcome. On debugging (winston-syslog.js) I see that it is trying to connect again. The event handler doesn't seem to exit. Is this intended or could this be a bug?

```
.on('close', () => {
        //
        // Attempt to reconnect on lost connection(s), progressively
        // increasing the amount of time between each try.
        //
        const interval = Math.pow(2, this.retries);
        this.connected = false;

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.retries++;
          **this.socket.connect(this.port, this.host);**
        }, interval * 1000);
      })
```

I understand that the line exists for attempting to reconnect on lost connections. But how do I go about actually closing the connection assuming one was created successfully, messages sent, and I no longer need the connection? 
If that line is commented, jest returns as expected.

The code is run on Centos 7 with node v 12.13.0 and:

```
"winston": "^3.2.1",
"winston-syslog": "^2.4.0",
"winston-transport": "^4.3.0"
```

Am I missing any configuration or clean up calls? Is there a way I can make the close() event handler exit?

Thanks!